# How do I output hyperlinks for Custom Object name fields in an apex:PageBlockTable

Tags: hyperlink, salesforce, fieldset

Sounds easy enough, but I'm taking the values output in my table from a number of field sets, so admin users can customise the columns that appear in the table.

Here's my functioning page block...

```
        <apex:pageBlock title="{!$Label.Search_Results}">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!SearchResults}" var="pictureGallerySearchResult" title="SearchResults">
            <apex:column headerValue="Image" styleClass="imageDataCell">
                <a target="_blank" href="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!pictureGallerySearchResult.ActualAttachment.Id}" >
                    <img class="searchResultImage" style="{!SearchResultsImageStyle}" src="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!pictureGallerySearchResult.ActualAttachment.Id}" alt="{!pictureGallerySearchResult.ActualAttachment.Name}"/>
                </a>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Test" value="{!pictureGallerySearchResult.Project[pictureGallerySearchResultField]}"/>
            <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Project__c.FieldSets.Picture_Gallery_Search_Results}" var="pictureGallerySearchResultField">
                <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Project__c.Fields[pictureGallerySearchResultField].label}" value="{!pictureGallerySearchResult.Project[pictureGallerySearchResultField]}"/>
            </apex:repeat>              
            <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Store__c.FieldSets.Picture_Gallery_Search_Results}" var="pictureGallerySearchResultField">
                <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Store__c.Fields[pictureGallerySearchResultField].label}" value="{!pictureGallerySearchResult.Store[pictureGallerySearchResultField]}"/>
            </apex:repeat>
            <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Visit__c.FieldSets.Picture_Gallery_Search_Results}" var="pictureGallerySearchResultField">
                <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Visit__c.Fields[pictureGallerySearchResultField].label}" value="{!pictureGallerySearchResult.Visit[pictureGallerySearchResultField]}"/>
            </apex:repeat>
            <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Photo_Attachment__c.FieldSets.Picture_Gallery_Search_Results}" var="pictureGallerySearchResultField">
                <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Photo_Attachment__c.Fields[pictureGallerySearchResultField].label}" value="{!pictureGallerySearchResult.PhotoAttachment[pictureGallerySearchResultField]}"/>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

You can see I've created a 'hard-coded' hyperlink for an image in the first column, but I want to dynamically hyperlink a field, if it is the name field for a custom object.

For example, if the fieldset...

```
$ObjectType.Project__c.FieldSets.Picture_Gallery_Search_Results
```

...contains the a field called 'Name', I want to insert a hyperlink that would take you to the salesforce page to view that project.

So firstly I need to be able to determine if the field is a custom object name field and secondly, output a hyper link rather than a label.

If anyone has any ideas, I would be most appreciative.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered doing this logic in an APEX controller/extension? After you execute your query, you can iterate over the results, determine what you want the hyperlink to be for each, and populate a map you expose to your Visualforce page keyed by some unique value in the search result (presumably ID) and the value would be the hyperlink. Then in your Visualforce iterator you can do map[SearchResult.Id] or whatever the key ends up being.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want a hyperlink for every value, only if it is the Name field of a custom object.  How do I code for field = 'Name' and how would I switch from rendering just text to rendering a hyperlink? Are you suggesting that the map would return the markup for a hyperlink?

Comment: I think in your case, if I'm reading the question right, you either want a hyperlink or nothing. If that is the case, you can leverage the "rendered" attribute on <apex:outputlink> to decide whether to show or hide that hyperlink based on the Name value being blank or not.

Comment: No, I always want to output the field value, but when the field is a custom object Name field, I want it to be a hyperlink to the relevant item within that custom object.  Remember it's outputting fields that users have entered into a fieldset, so it could be any field.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest using a Map to keep track of whether to make it a hyperlink or not -- Map<String, Boolean>. Then for each ID, execute your logic in APEX to check, and enter yes/no into the map. Then in Visualforce, you would have two apex tags -- <apex:outputText> and <apex:outputLink>. They each would have a rendered attribute of {!map[obj.Id]} or {!NOT(map[obj.Id])}, and you would dynamically invoke one of the two and show whatever you want within.

Comment: I'd considered the option of doing both a label and a hyper link and somehow hiding the appropriate one, so your idea of using a Map was perfect. Given the fact the fields are completely dynamic, the syntax of passing through the appropriate look up value as an argument was the tricky part. I'll post what I eventually ended up with subsequently....

Thanks for your assistance Michael.

Answer (score 1):

```
<apex:column headerValue="{!$Label.Filename}">{!pictureGallerySearchResult.ActualAttachment.Name}</apex:column>
<apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Project__c.FieldSets.Picture_Gallery_Search_Results}" var="pictureGallerySearchResultField">
    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Project__c.Fields[pictureGallerySearchResultField].label}">
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!pictureGallerySearchResult.Project[pictureGallerySearchResultField]}" rendered="{!NOT(ShowResultFieldHyperlinkMap[$ObjectType.Project__c.Fields[pictureGallerySearchResultField].label])}"/>
        <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Project__c.View, pictureGallerySearchResult.Project['Id'])}" rendered="{!ShowResultFieldHyperlinkMap[$ObjectType.Project__c.Fields[pictureGallerySearchResultField].label]}" styleClass="resultFieldHyperlink">
            <apex:outputLabel value="{!pictureGallerySearchResult.Project[pictureGallerySearchResultField]}" styleClass="resultFieldHyperlinkLabel"/>
        </apex:outputLink>
    </apex:column>
</apex:repeat>
```